# lightgallery doesnt work good

Tags: gallery, lightgallery

My gallery starts from my first img,but at counter its number 2, and when go  back to first picture it shows me nothing,  just black window (at first it  shows me "src undefined", but now just black window). I want my first 
picture to be number 1 in counter etc. i am not sure where is the problem, so i gave you js code from lightgallery here

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var defaults = {

        mode: 'lg-slide',

        // Ex : 'ease'
        cssEasing: 'ease',

        //'for jquery animation'
        easing: 'linear',
        speed: 600,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        addClass: '',
        startClass: 'lg-start-zoom',
        backdropDuration: 150,
        hideBarsDelay: 6000,

        useLeft: false,

        closable: true,
        loop: true,
        escKey: true,
        keyPress: true,
        controls: true,
        slideEndAnimatoin: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: false,
        mousewheel: true,

        getCaptionFromTitleOrAlt: true,

        // .lg-item || '.lg-sub-html'
        appendSubHtmlTo: '.lg-sub-html',

        subHtmlSelectorRelative: false,

        /**
         * @desc number of preload slides
         * will exicute only after the current slide is fully loaded.
         *
         * @ex you clicked on 4th image and if preload = 1 then 3rd slide and 5th
         * slide will be loaded in the background after the 4th slide is fully loaded..
         * if preload is 2 then 2nd 3rd 5th 6th slides will be preloaded.. ... ...
         *
         */
        preload: 0,
        showAfterLoad: true,
        selector: '',
        selectWithin: '',
        nextHtml: '',
        prevHtml: '',

        // 0, 1
        index: false,

        iframeMaxWidth: '100%',

        download: true,
        counter: true,
        appendCounterTo: '.lg-toolbar',

        swipeThreshold: 50,
        enableSwipe: true,
        enableDrag: true,

        dynamic: false,
        dynamicEl: [],
        galleryId: 1
    };

    function Plugin(element, options) {

        // Current lightGallery element
        this.el = element;

        // Current jquery element
        this.$el = $(element);

        // lightGallery settings
        this.s = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // When using dynamic mode, ensure dynamicEl is an array
        if (this.s.dynamic && this.s.dynamicEl !== 'undefined' && this.s.dynamicEl.constructor === Array && !this.s.dynamicEl.length) {
            throw ('When using dynamic mode, you must also define dynamicEl as an Array.');
        }

        // lightGallery modules
        this.modules = {};

        // false when lightgallery complete first slide;
        this.lGalleryOn = false;

        this.lgBusy = false;

        // Timeout function for hiding controls;
        this.hideBartimeout = false;

        // To determine browser supports for touch events;
        this.isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);

        // Disable hideControlOnEnd if sildeEndAnimation is true
        if (this.s.slideEndAnimatoin) {
            this.s.hideControlOnEnd = false;
        }

        // Gallery items
        if (this.s.dynamic) {
            this.$items = this.s.dynamicEl;
        } else {
            if (this.s.selector === 'this') {
                this.$items = this.$el;
            } else if (this.s.selector !== '') {
                if (this.s.selectWithin) {
                    this.$items = $(this.s.selectWithin).find(this.s.selector);
                } else {
                    this.$items = this.$el.find($(this.s.selector));
                }
            } else {
                this.$items = this.$el.children();
            }
        }

        // .lg-item
        this.$slide = '';

        // .lg-outer
        this.$outer = '';

        this.init();

        return this;
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function() {

        var _this = this;

        // s.preload should not be more than $item.length
        if (_this.s.preload > _this.$items.length) {
            _this.s.preload = _this.$items.length;
        }

        // if dynamic option is enabled execute immediately
        var _hash = window.location.hash;
        if (_hash.indexOf('lg=' + this.s.galleryId) > 0) {

            _this.index = parseInt(_hash.split('&slide=')[1], 10);

            $('body').addClass('lg-from-hash');
            if (!$('body').hasClass('lg-on')) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.build(_this.index);
                });

                $('body').addClass('lg-on');
            }
        }

        if (_this.s.dynamic) {

            _this.$el.trigger('onBeforeOpen.lg');

            _this.index = _this.s.index || 0;

            // prevent accidental double execution
            if (!$('body').hasClass('lg-on')) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.build(_this.index);
                    $('body').addClass('lg-on');
                });
            }
        } else {

            // Using different namespace for click because click event should not unbind if selector is same object('this')
            _this.$items.on('click.lgcustom', function(event) {

                // For IE8
                try {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.preventDefault();
                } catch (er) {
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }

                _this.$el.trigger('onBeforeOpen.lg');

                _this.index = _this.s.index || _this.$items.index(this);

                // prevent accidental double execution
                if (!$('body').hasClass('lg-on')) {
                    _this.build(_this.index);
                    $('body').addClass('lg-on');
                }
            });
        }

    };

    Plugin.prototype.build = function(index) {

        var _this = this;

        _this.structure();

        // module constructor
        $.each($.fn.lightGallery.modules, function(key) {
            _this.modules[key] = new $.fn.lightGallery.modules[key](_this.el);
        });

        // initiate slide function
        _this.slide(index, false, false, false);

        if (_this.s.keyPress) {
            _this.keyPress();
        }

        if (_this.$items.length > 1) {

            _this.arrow();

            setTimeout(function() {
                _this.enableDrag();
                _this.enableSwipe();
            }, 50);

            if (_this.s.mousewheel) {
                _this.mousewheel();
            }
        } else {
            _this.$slide.on('click.lg', function() {
                _this.$el.trigger('onSlideClick.lg');
            });
        }

        _this.counter();

        _this.closeGallery();

        _this.$el.trigger('onAfterOpen.lg');

        // Hide controllers if mouse doesn't move for some period
        _this.$outer.on('mousemove.lg click.lg touchstart.lg', function() {

            _this.$outer.removeClass('lg-hide-items');

            clearTimeout(_this.hideBartimeout);

            // Timeout will be cleared on each slide movement also
            _this.hideBartimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                _this.$outer.addClass('lg-hide-items');
            }, _this.s.hideBarsDelay);

        });

        _this.$outer.trigger('mousemove.lg');

    };

    Plugin.prototype.structure = function() {
        var list = '';
        var controls = '';

        var subHtmlCont = '';
        var template;
        var _this = this;

        $('body').append('<div class="lg-backdrop"></div>');
        $('.lg-backdrop').css('transition-duration', this.s.backdropDuration + 'ms');

        // Create gallery items
        for (var i = 0; i < this.$items.length; i++) {
            list += '<div class="lg-item"></div>';
        }







    Plugin.prototype.isVideo = function(src, index) {

        var html;
        if (this.s.dynamic) {
            html = this.s.dynamicEl[index].html;
        } else {
            html = this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-html');
        }

        if (!src) {
            if(html) {
                return {
                    html5: true
                };
            } else {
                console.error('lightGallery :- data-src is not pvovided on slide item ' + (index + 1) + '. Please make sure the selector property is properly configured. More info - http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html-markup.html');
                return false;
            }
        }

        var youtube = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com|be-nocookie\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/)?([a-z0-9\-\_\%]+)/i);
        var vimeo = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+)/i);
        var dailymotion = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?dai.ly\/([0-9a-z\-_]+)/i);
        var vk = src.match(/\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:vk\.com|vkontakte\.ru)\/(?:video_ext\.php\?)(.*)/i);

        if (youtube) {
            return {
                youtube: youtube
            };
        } else if (vimeo) {
            return {
                vimeo: vimeo
            };
        } else if (dailymotion) {
            return {
                dailymotion: dailymotion
            };
        } else if (vk) {
            return {
                vk: vk
            };
        }
    };

    /**
     *  @desc Create image counter
     *  Ex: 1/10
     */
    Plugin.prototype.counter = function() {
        if (this.s.counter) {
            $(this.s.appendCounterTo).append('<div id="lg-counter"><span id="lg-counter-current">' + (parseInt(this.index, 10) + 1) + '</span> / <span id="lg-counter-all">' + this.$items.length + '</span></div>');
        }
    };

    /**
     *  @desc add sub-html into the slide
     *  @param {Number} index - index of the slide
     */
    Plugin.prototype.addHtml = function(index) {
        var subHtml = null;
        var subHtmlUrl;
        var $currentEle;
        if (this.s.dynamic) {
            if (this.s.dynamicEl[index].subHtmlUrl) {
                subHtmlUrl = this.s.dynamicEl[index].subHtmlUrl;
            } else {
                subHtml = this.s.dynamicEl[index].subHtml;
            }
        } else {
            $currentEle = this.$items.eq(index);
            if ($currentEle.attr('data-sub-html-url')) {
                subHtmlUrl = $currentEle.attr('data-sub-html-url');
            } else {
                subHtml = $currentEle.attr('data-sub-html');
                if (this.s.getCaptionFromTitleOrAlt && !subHtml) {
                    subHtml = $currentEle.attr('title') || $currentEle.find('img').first().attr('alt');
                }
            }
        }

        if (!subHtmlUrl) {
            if (typeof subHtml !== 'undefined' && subHtml !== null) {

                // get first letter of subhtml
                // if first letter starts with . or # get the html form the jQuery object
                var fL = subHtml.substring(0, 1);
                if (fL === '.' || fL === '#') {
                    if (this.s.subHtmlSelectorRelative && !this.s.dynamic) {
                        subHtml = $currentEle.find(subHtml).html();
                    } else {
                        subHtml = $(subHtml).html();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                subHtml = '';
            }
        }

        if (this.s.appendSubHtmlTo === '.lg-sub-html') {

            if (subHtmlUrl) {
                this.$outer.find(this.s.appendSubHtmlTo).load(subHtmlUrl);
            } else {
                this.$outer.find(this.s.appendSubHtmlTo).html(subHtml);
            }

        } else {

            if (subHtmlUrl) {
                this.$slide.eq(index).load(subHtmlUrl);
            } else {
                this.$slide.eq(index).append(subHtml);
            }
        }

        // Add lg-empty-html class if title doesn't exist
        if (typeof subHtml !== 'undefined' && subHtml !== null) {
            if (subHtml === '') {
                this.$outer.find(this.s.appendSubHtmlTo).addClass('lg-empty-html');
            } else {
                this.$outer.find(this.s.appendSubHtmlTo).removeClass('lg-empty-html');
            }
        }

        this.$el.trigger('onAfterAppendSubHtml.lg', [index]);
    };

    /**
     *  @desc Preload slides
     *  @param {Number} index - index of the slide
     */
    Plugin.prototype.preload = function(index) {
        var i = 1;
        var j = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= this.s.preload; i++) {
            if (i >= this.$items.length - index) {
                break;
            }

            this.loadContent(index + i, false, 0);
        }

        for (j = 1; j <= this.s.preload; j++) {
            if (index - j < 0) {
                break;
            }

            this.loadContent(index - j, false, 0);
        }
    };

    /**
     *  @desc Load slide content into slide.
     *  @param {Number} index - index of the slide.
     *  @param {Boolean} rec - if true call loadcontent() function again.
     *  @param {Boolean} delay - delay for adding complete class. it is 0 except first time.
     */
    Plugin.prototype.loadContent = function(index, rec, delay) {

        var _this = this;
        var _hasPoster = false;
        var _$img;
        var _src;
        var _poster;
        var _srcset;
        var _sizes;
        var _html;
        var getResponsiveSrc = function(srcItms) {
            var rsWidth = [];
            var rsSrc = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < srcItms.length; i++) {
                var __src = srcItms[i].split(' ');

                // Manage empty space
                if (__src[0] === '') {
                    __src.splice(0, 1);
                }

                rsSrc.push(__src[0]);
                rsWidth.push(__src[1]);
            }

            var wWidth = $(window).width();
            for (var j = 0; j < rsWidth.length; j++) {
                if (parseInt(rsWidth[j], 10) > wWidth) {
                    _src = rsSrc[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        if (_this.s.dynamic) {

            if (_this.s.dynamicEl[index].poster) {
                _hasPoster = true;
                _poster = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].poster;
            }

            _html = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].html;
            _src = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].src;

            if (_this.s.dynamicEl[index].responsive) {
                var srcDyItms = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].responsive.split(',');
                getResponsiveSrc(srcDyItms);
            }

            _srcset = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].srcset;
            _sizes = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].sizes;

        } else {

            if (_this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-poster')) {
                _hasPoster = true;
                _poster = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-poster');
            }

            _html = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-html');
            _src = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('href') || _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-src');

            if (_this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-responsive')) {
                var srcItms = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-responsive').split(',');
                getResponsiveSrc(srcItms);
            }

            _srcset = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-srcset');
            _sizes = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-sizes');

        }

        if (_src || _srcset || _sizes || _poster) {

        var iframe = false;
        if (_this.s.dynamic) {
            if (_this.s.dynamicEl[index].iframe) {
                iframe = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (_this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-iframe') === 'true') {
                iframe = true;
            }
        }

        var _isVideo = _this.isVideo(_src, index);
        if (!_this.$slide.eq(index).hasClass('lg-loaded')) {
            if (iframe) {
                _this.$slide.eq(index).prepend('<div class="lg-video-cont lg-has-iframe" style="max-width:' + _this.s.iframeMaxWidth + '"><div class="lg-video"><iframe class="lg-object" frameborder="0" src="' + _src + '"  allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div></div>');
            } else if (_hasPoster) {
                var videoClass = '';
                if (_isVideo && _isVideo.youtube) {
                    videoClass = 'lg-has-youtube';
                } else if (_isVideo && _isVideo.vimeo) {
                    videoClass = 'lg-has-vimeo';
                } else {
                    videoClass = 'lg-has-html5';
                }

                _this.$slide.eq(index).prepend('<div class="lg-video-cont ' + videoClass + ' "><div class="lg-video"><span class="lg-video-play"></span><img class="lg-object lg-has-poster" src="' + _poster + '" /></div></div>');

            } else if (_isVideo) {
                _this.$slide.eq(index).prepend('<div class="lg-video-cont "><div class="lg-video"></div></div>');
                _this.$el.trigger('hasVideo.lg', [index, _src, _html]);
            } else {
                _this.$slide.eq(index).prepend('<div class="lg-img-wrap"><img class="lg-object lg-image" src="' + _src + '" /></div>');
            }

            _this.$el.trigger('onAferAppendSlide.lg', [index]);

            _$img = _this.$slide.eq(index).find('.lg-object');
            if (_sizes) {
                _$img.attr('sizes', _sizes);
            }

            if (_srcset) {
                _$img.attr('srcset', _srcset);
                try {
                    picturefill({
                        elements: [_$img[0]]
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.warn('lightGallery :- If you want srcset to be supported for older browser please include picturefil version 2 javascript library in your document.');
                }
            }

            if (this.s.appendSubHtmlTo !== '.lg-sub-html') {
                _this.addHtml(index);
            }

            _this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-loaded');
        }

        _this.$slide.eq(index).find('.lg-object').on('load.lg error.lg', function() {

            // For first time add some delay for displaying the start animation.
            var _speed = 0;

            // Do not change the delay value because it is required for zoom plugin.
            // If gallery opened from direct url (hash) speed value should be 0
            if (delay && !$('body').hasClass('lg-from-hash')) {
                _speed = delay;
            }

            setTimeout(function() {
                _this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-complete');
                _this.$el.trigger('onSlideItemLoad.lg', [index, delay || 0]);
            }, _speed);

        });

        // @todo check load state for html5 videos
        if (_isVideo && _isVideo.html5 && !_hasPoster) {
            _this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-complete');
        }

        if (rec === true) {
            if (!_this.$slide.eq(index).hasClass('lg-complete')) {
                _this.$slide.eq(index).find('.lg-object').on('load.lg error.lg', function() {
                    _this.preload(index);
                });
            } else {
                _this.preload(index);
            }
        }

        }
    };


    Plugin.prototype.slide = function(index, fromTouch, fromThumb, direction) {

        var _prevIndex = this.$outer.find('.lg-current').index();
        var _this = this;

        // Prevent if multiple call
        // Required for hsh plugin
        if (_this.lGalleryOn && (_prevIndex === index)) {
            return;
        }

        var _length = this.$slide.length;
        var _time = _this.lGalleryOn ? this.s.speed : 0;

        if (!_this.lgBusy) {

            if (this.s.download) {
                var _src;
                if (_this.s.dynamic) {
                    _src = _this.s.dynamicEl[index].downloadUrl !== false && (_this.s.dynamicEl[index].downloadUrl || _this.s.dynamicEl[index].src);
                } else {
                    _src = _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-download-url') !== 'false' && (_this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-download-url') || _this.$items.eq(index).attr('href') || _this.$items.eq(index).attr('data-src'));

                }

                if (_src) {
                    $('#lg-download').attr('href', _src);
                    _this.$outer.removeClass('lg-hide-download');
                } else {
                    _this.$outer.addClass('lg-hide-download');
                }
            }

            this.$el.trigger('onBeforeSlide.lg', [_prevIndex, index, fromTouch, fromThumb]);

            _this.lgBusy = true;

            clearTimeout(_this.hideBartimeout);

            // Add title if this.s.appendSubHtmlTo === lg-sub-html
            if (this.s.appendSubHtmlTo === '.lg-sub-html') {

                // wait for slide animation to complete
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.addHtml(index);
                }, _time);
            }

            this.arrowDisable(index);

            if (!direction) {
                if (index < _prevIndex) {
                    direction = 'prev';
                } else if (index > _prevIndex) {
                    direction = 'next';
                }
            }

            if (!fromTouch) {

                // remove all transitions
                _this.$outer.addClass('lg-no-trans');

                this.$slide.removeClass('lg-prev-slide lg-next-slide');

                if (direction === 'prev') {

                    //prevslide
                    this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-prev-slide');
                    this.$slide.eq(_prevIndex).addClass('lg-next-slide');
                } else {

                    // next slide
                    this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-next-slide');
                    this.$slide.eq(_prevIndex).addClass('lg-prev-slide');
                }

                // give 50 ms for browser to add/remove class
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.$slide.removeClass('lg-current');

                    //_this.$slide.eq(_prevIndex).removeClass('lg-current');
                    _this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-current');

                    // reset all transitions
                    _this.$outer.removeClass('lg-no-trans');
                }, 50);
            } else {

                this.$slide.removeClass('lg-prev-slide lg-current lg-next-slide');
                var touchPrev;
                var touchNext;
                if (_length > 2) {
                    touchPrev = index - 1;
                    touchNext = index + 1;

                    if ((index === 0) && (_prevIndex === _length - 1)) {

                        // next slide
                        touchNext = 0;
                        touchPrev = _length - 1;
                    } else if ((index === _length - 1) && (_prevIndex === 0)) {

                        // prev slide
                        touchNext = 0;
                        touchPrev = _length - 1;
                    }

                } else {
                    touchPrev = 0;
                    touchNext = 1;
                }

                if (direction === 'prev') {
                    _this.$slide.eq(touchNext).addClass('lg-next-slide');
                } else {
                    _this.$slide.eq(touchPrev).addClass('lg-prev-slide');
                }

                _this.$slide.eq(index).addClass('lg-current');
            }

            if (_this.lGalleryOn) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.loadContent(index, true, 0);
                }, this.s.speed + 50);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    _this.lgBusy = false;
                    _this.$el.trigger('onAfterSlide.lg', [_prevIndex, index, fromTouch, fromThumb]);
                }, this.s.speed);

            } else {
                _this.loadContent(index, true, _this.s.backdropDuration);

                _this.lgBusy = false;
                _this.$el.trigger('onAfterSlide.lg', [_prevIndex, index, fromTouch, fromThumb]);
            }

            _this.lGalleryOn = true;

            if (this.s.counter) {
                $('#lg-counter-current').text(index + 1);
            }

        }
        _this.index = index;

    };




$(document).ready(function() {
     for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++){
  $('#lightgallery' + i).lightGallery({

    pager: true
  });
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<section id="galler" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:center;">
    <div class="demo-gallery">
        <ul id="lightgallery0">
            <h4>First love 29.07.2018.</h4>
            <li data-responsive="img/29.07.2018/1.jpg 375, img/29.07.2018/1.jpg 480, img/29.07.2018/1.jpg 800" data-src="img/29.07.2018/1.jpg" data-sub-html="<h4>Solar Matinee - First Love</h4> " style='display:inline-block;' data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/29.07.2018/1.jpg">
                    <div class="demo-gallery-poster">
                        <img src="img/zoom.png">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-responsive="img/29.07.2018/2.jpg 375, img/29.07.2018/2.jpg 800" class="none" data-src="img/29.07.2018/2.jpg" data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
            </li>
            <li data-responsive="img/29.07.2018/3.jpg 375, img/29.07.2018/3.jpg 800" class="none" data-src="img/29.07.2018/3.jpg" data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure you have no syntax error on console? I got "unexpected end of input" error in last line. Can you please share your HTML layout too?

Comment: I got just this error in console

Comment: lightgallery.js:423 lightGallery :- data-src is not pvovided on slide item 1. Please make sure the selector property is properly configured. More info - http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html-markup.html

Comment: It's hard to answer for me without the HTML layout. Possibly the div with "lightgallery" ID.

Comment: Where i can put html code? its too long for comment?

Comment: Please edit your answer and include your HTML layout.

Comment: I put it now. Thank you!

Comment: The body of  **Plugin.prototype.structure** is not complete. Paste the correct definition of the function.

Comment: My code is then too long, do i have any option how to paste all my js code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your js script is missing some lines, to minimize the error possibility I called them over CDN and made little changes on your script. Have a look at snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=lightgallery]").lightGallery({ /* no need to loop, just select elements which starting with "lightgallery" */
    pager: true,
    selector: 'li' /* we need to show which elements are our items (to not assume h4 as a slider item [reason of "data-src is not pvovided on slide item 1" error]) */
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #152836
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li {
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a {
      border: 3px solid #FFF;
      border-radius: 3px;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a>img {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover>img {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
      transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a .demo-gallery-poster {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
      transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-top: -10px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery>ul>li a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a>img {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: -o-transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      transition: transform 0.15s ease 0s;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover>img {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
      transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover .demo-gallery-poster>img {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a .demo-gallery-poster {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
      transition: background-color 0.15s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a .demo-gallery-poster>img {
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-top: -10px;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
      transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .justified-gallery>a:hover .demo-gallery-poster {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    
    .demo-gallery .video .demo-gallery-poster img {
      height: 48px;
      margin-left: -24px;
      margin-top: -24px;
      opacity: 0.8;
      width: 48px;
    }
    
    .demo-gallery.dark>ul>li a {
      border: 3px solid #04070a;
    }
    
    .home .demo-gallery {
      padding-bottom: 80px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="home">

  <div class="demo-gallery">
    <ul id="lightgallery0">
      <h4>First love 29.07.2018.</h4>
      <li data-src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=1" data-sub-html="<h4>Solar Matinee - First Love</h4> " style='display:inline-block;' data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
        <a href="">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=1">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="none" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=2" data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
        <a href="">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=2">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="none" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=3" data-pinterest-text="Pin it">
        <a href="">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000000/fff&text=3">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/picturefill/2.3.1/picturefill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: selector: ' li '   /* This solve the problem! Thank you so much!!